# I can't Interrogate the Database

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am doing an apllication using the MEAN stack. My problem is that I can't access to my database using mongoose and I don't know why. I copied the code of a previous application (which worked perfectly) and adapted it to my application. It is connected to the database. i have compared a hundred time both codes and nothing appear to be wrong.

let's go for the codes

the server :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/EnergyHive.js');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://10.70.64.56/PowerConsumption'); //connection a la Database
mongoose.connection.on("open", function(){ 
  console.log("=---= mongodb is connected!"); //confirmation de connection
});

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public/images
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', '/images/favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/statics', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

the router and api code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var EnergyHive = mongoose.model('EnergyHive');


/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  console.log("=---= Bonjour");
});

module.exports = router;
```

//API

```
var express = require('express');
    var api = express.Router();
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var EnergyHive = mongoose.model('EnergyHive');

    console.log("=---= API start");

    api.get('/power_monitor', function(req, res, next){
      console.log("=---= power_monitor");

      var day = new Date().getDate();
      var month = new Date().getMonth()+1;
      var year = new Date().getFullYear();

      console.log("=---= day : ", day);
      console.log("=---= month : ", month);
      console.log("=---= year : ", year);

      EnergyHive.find({"consult_day": day, "consult_month": month, "consult_year": year}, function(err, Data){
        console.log("=---= in the collection !");
        if(err){
         console.log("=---= Error" + err);
         return next(err); 
       }
        else {
          console.log("=---= docs recuperé !", Data);
        }
        res.json(Data);
      });
    });

    module.exports = api;
```

the angular

```
var app = angular.module('powerMonitor', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

  $stateProvider.state('home',{
      url: '/power_monitor',
      templateUrl: '/statics/templates/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
    });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/power_monitor');
}]);

app.factory('historicFactory', [function() {

    var h = {};

    h.createHistoric = function(choix, value) {

      if (choix == 0) {
        return tab = [
          {date: "January",   consumption: 2.30, cost: 2.30*0.057265*30*24}, 
          {date: "February",  consumption: 2.35, cost: 2.35*0.057265*30*24},
          {date: "March",     consumption: 2.32, cost: 2.32*0.057265*30*24}, 
          {date: "April",     consumption: 2.31, cost: 2.31*0.057265*30*24}, 
          {date: "may",       consumption: 2.35, cost: 2.35*0.057265*30*24}, 
          {date: "June",      consumption: 2.35, cost: 2.35*0.057265*30*24}, 
          {date: "July",      consumption: 2.41, cost: 2.41*0.057265*30*24}, 
          {date: "August",    consumption: 2.37, cost: 2.37*0.057265*30*24}, 
          {date: "September", consumption: 2.35, cost: 2.35*0.057265*30*24},  
          {date: "October",   consumption: 2.40, cost: 2.40*0.057265*30*24}
        ];
      } else if (choix == 1) {
        return tab  = [
          {date: "2015-W35", consumption: 0.52, cost: 0.52*0.057265*7*24}, 
          {date: "2015-W36", consumption: 0.55, cost: 0.55*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W37", consumption: 0.48, cost: 0.48*0.057265*7*24}, 
          {date: "2015-W38", consumption: 0.50, cost: 0.50*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W39", consumption: 0.49, cost: 0.49*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W40", consumption: 0.48, cost: 0.48*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W41", consumption: 0.50, cost: 0.50*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W42", consumption: 0.51, cost: 0.51*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W43", consumption: 0.49, cost: 0.49*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W44", consumption: 0.49, cost: 0.49*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W45", consumption: 0.51, cost: 0.51*0.057265*7*24},
          {date: "2015-W46", consumption: 0.49, cost: 0.49*0.057265*7*24}
        ];
      } else if (choix == 2) {
          return tab = [
            {date: "01/11/2015", consumption: 0.10, cost: 0.10*0.057265*24}, 
            {date: "02/11/2015", consumption: 0.09, cost: 0.09*0.057265*24}, 
            {date: "03/11/2015", consumption: 0.08, cost: 0.08*0.057265*24}, 
            {date: "04/11/2015", consumption: 0.08, cost: 0.08*0.057265*24}, 
            {date: "05/11/2015", consumption: 0.10, cost: 0.10*0.057265*24}, 
            {date: "06/11/2015", consumption: 0.10, cost: 0.10*0.057265*24},
            {date: "07/11/2015", consumption: 0.11, cost: 0.11*0.057265*24},
            {date: "08/11/2015", consumption: 0.09, cost: 0.09*0.057265*24},
            {date: "09/11/2015", consumption: 0.08, cost: 0.08*0.057265*24},
            {date: "10/11/2015", consumption: 0.10, cost: 0.10*0.057265*24}
          ];

      }
    };

    return h;
  }]);

app.factory('costFactory', [function(){
  var c = {};

  c.calculCost = function (tabValue, pricekW, currentCost){
    var i = tabValue.length - 1;

    cost = currentCost + (tabValue[i].value * tabValue[i].time * pricekW); 
    cost = cost.toFixed(2);
    return cost = parseFloat(cost);
    console.log("type of c.cost apres calcul: ", typeof(f));


  };
  return c;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'historicFactory', 'costFactory',function($scope, historicFactory, costFactory) {

    $scope.currentValue = 0;
    $scope.currentTime = 0;
    $scope.costBis = 0;
    $scope.tabValue = [];
    $scope.pricekW = 0.057265;
    $scope.historicOptions = [
      {id: 0, value: "month"},
      {id: 1, value: "week" }, 
      {id: 2, value: "day"  }
    ];


    $scope.addValue = function (){
      $scope.tabValue.push({value: $scope.currentValue, time: $scope.currentTime});
      $scope.cost = costFactory.calculCost($scope.tabValue, $scope.pricekW, $scope.costBis);
      $scope.costBis = $scope.cost;
      console.log("cost:", $scope.cost);
    };

    $scope.getSelectedValue = function() {

      $scope.historic = historicFactory.createHistoric($scope.choice,$scope.value);
    };

    $scope.getSaveValue = function() {
      $scope.saving = saveFactory.calculsave($scope.newTemperature, $scope.newTime, $scope.pricekW);
    };



  }]);
```

It's a lot of code I know, sorry.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is there some error that you are receiving?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko No there is nothing, my console tells my I'm connected to the database. The consol.log displayed are : console.log("=---= mongodb is connected!");    console.log("=---= Bonjour");    and console.log("=---= API start"); and then nothing. but my templates are displayed correctly, I can interract with my application

Comment: What is it exactly that goes against your expectations? This is not clear from your description.

Comment: when I arrive on the /power_monitor (which is the default page) the server is supposed to get the data from the EnergyHive collection but nothing happens (the console.log("=---= power_monitor"); doesn't print on the console)

Comment: `power_monitor` is not the default route. The default route is defined like this: `.get('/', ...`. According to your code, you should access the route in question like this: `http://yoursite/api/power_monitor`.

Comment: yeah you're right i'm just doing $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/power_monitor'); with angular so you always redirected to this route (that's what i meant by default page, my bad). i'm doing /api/power_monitor with the api module (I did the same way my previous app and it worked)

Comment: Well, since `=---= Bonjour` is printed to the console, it is clear that the home page route is executed instead of the power_monitor route. Your problem has nothing to do with MongoDB. The problem is your route setup + Angular setup. If you look at the network tab in Chrome, I am pretty sure you won't see a request to `/api/power_monitor`.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't see what's wrong. Again i did the same way on another app and it worked :(

Comment: I don't see your Angular code setup, so I can't tell you what's wrong. Please open the Network tab in Development tools in Chrome and see what requests are being issued by the browser.

Comment: There is nothing in the Network tab. I editied my post with the angular setup

Comment: I don't see `/api/` in your Angular setup. just `/power_monitor`.

Comment: I tried adding /api/ but nothing change

Comment: Okay, you'll need to learn how to use the Network tab in Chrome. Here's the documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network - you can also google some tutorials on the web. You have to find out what exact request is issued by your browser - to which exact URL. Until then I cannot help you.

Comment: So i checked on the network panel and still no request

Comment: do you go there *before* opening the page? If you don't see the request, then something is definitely wrong with your Angular setup.

Comment: what do you mean by go there before opening the page ?

Comment: Open the network tab and then reload the page

Comment: I already did it and still no request

Comment: there is no way to help you, unless you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).